# Performing segue (unwind?) in an UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c, segue, uialertaction

I have all this in my Main.storyboard.
NavigationController  >  ViewOneController  >  ViewTwoController

At end of my game in ViewController2, I would like to return to the ViewController1 by using a segue in my UIAlertAction.

I understand that I leave the code in UIAlertAction handler. Then:

`{
  // some segue function
}`

How do I link this back to ViewController1 where I can start a new game?

I don't know which segue to type in the ViewController1.m, is this an unwindSegue and how would I link them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not being really clear, but I'm guessing you want to unwind back to the initial ViewController. Try this:

**`Objective-C`**

[image: Objective-C code]

**`Swift 3`**

[image: Swift 3 code]

Comment: Thank you.  Works very well.